# Combobox save changed records Id

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

how I can to get id when I changing records from combobox?
I have to write the changed data to apex.

```
  <lightning-combobox data-id = {pos.Id}
                        value = {pos.Status__c}
                        options = {inputStatus}
                        onchange = {handleInputStatus}>
    </lightning-combobox>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do not add screenshots of your code, and instead, add code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-*` attributes are accesible via the [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) property

> **In JavaScript**
> The property name of a custom data attribute is the same as the HTML attribute without the data- prefix, and removes single dashes (-) for when to capitalize the property’s “camelCased” name.

[`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) holds a reference to the HTMLElement, so that's how `handleInputStatus` should be:

```
async handleInputStatus(event) {
    this.statusInput = event.detail.value;
    console.log(this.statusInput);
    const elemId = event.target.dataset.Id;
    console.log('elemId:', elemId);
}
```

By the way, as glls said, please use code snippet instead over attaching screenshot of your code. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557)